# how to add all servers in open vpn network

Tags: openvpn

I had installed and setup openvpn in a server and within that openvpn network I am able to login to the server that I had installed openvpn into.

Now, the requirement is : I need to login to all servers in my cloud with that openvpn through private ip.

How do I do this and also if I create new server, how could it be automatically allowed to login through the openvpn network.

Comment: You need to add the necessary routes on all machines.

Answer (score 0):

Openvpn is both an interface manager (with encryption) *and* a router.

So you need to push some route to your clients from your server then every clients will be able to reach the server it is connected to.

Show the base of your config so someone will give you further directions.